# Getting objects with today's date in Rest API

Tags: rest, filter, api

I need to fetch task objects which are completing today using Rest API , Can anyone please suggest how can we use today option to filer the data?

I am using below query:

```
/api/Objects/Task?$filter=AssignmentFinish ge '" + today.toISOString() + "'
```

but getting an error as given below:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'\"   today.toISOString()

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: is `AssignmentFinish` is date field?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can filter dates in REST:

```
$filter=StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00%3a00%3a00'
```

This filters for items created after 01-Jan-2014, 00:00:00.

So to filter between two date ranges, simply add another condition to the filter:

```
$filter=(StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (EndDate le datetime'2014-04-30T00%3a00%3a00')
```

This filters for items created between 01-Jan-2014 and 01-May-2014.

Just create your dates in the format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`, and then encode it (or simply use `%3a` instead of the colons).

Comment: Does this answer helps you?